# using ngrok with python

Tags: python, ngrok, pyngrok

How can I start ngrok with python and copy the public link just executing python script ?

I tried with subprocess but it only launched the 'ngrok http 80' command , I want to copy the public link.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pyngrok`](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library, which you can install with `pip install pyngrok` or put in [your requirements file](https://learnpython.com/blog/python-requirements-file/). Then open a tunnel and grab the public URL you're asking for like this:

```py
from pyngrok import ngrok

# Open a HTTP tunnel on the default port 80
# <NgrokTunnel: "http://<public_sub>.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:80">
http_tunnel = ngrok.connect()
print(" * ngrok tunnel \"{}\" -> \"http://127.0.0.1\"".format(http_tunnel.public_url))
```

Comment: but how can i get the link ?

Comment: The [connect()](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pyngrok.ngrok.connect) method returns a `NgrokTunnel`, which has a `public_url` field. I updated the example to show how to print this.